# Code not working. Ask user for 2 characters and search text file for strings that start with those two characters

Tags: java, algorithm, search

The goal of this code is to ask the user for 2 characters, and output all the movies starting with those two characters from a text file. Should I make a new method for getTitle()? In MovieUsage it doesn't work right whether I use contains or equals. Not sure what to do after this. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class Movie
{
    private String name;

    public Movie (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Movie> loadDatabase() throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<Movie> list = new ArrayList<>();

        File f = new File("db.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);

        while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            String name = inputFile.nextLine();
            int year = inputFile.nextInt();
            inputFile.nextLine();
            String genre = inputFile.nextLine();

            Movie m = new Movie(name);
            list.add(m);
        }
        return list;
    }
       public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String toSTring()
    {
        return name;
    }
}

public class MovieUsage
{
    public static void printRandomMovie(ArrayList<Movie> database)
    {
        System.out.println("Picking random movie from " + database.size() + " movies");

        Random rng = new Random();
        int subscript = rng.nextInt(database.size());

        System.out.println("Your movie is: " + database.get(subscript));
    }

    public static void printMatchingMovies(ArrayList<Movie> database, String searchString) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int numMatches = 0;

        for (Movie temp : database)
        {
            if (temp.contains(searchString))
            {
                System.out.println(temp);
                numMatches++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of matches: " + numMatches);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Movie> database = Movie.loadDatabase();

        System.out.println("Movie search by two characters. Enter two characters.");
        String searchString = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Movies that start with " + searchString);

        printMatchingMovies(database, searchString);
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help in advanced.

Comment: Just a tip, always post code as text here. It makes it a lot easier for us to help you, as we can copy past your code into our IDE and find the error

Comment: @GBlodgett  So I should make a method that gets the movie title? Just realized I didn't add any comments. It's my first class for computer science.

Comment: Should I copy and paste? Or should I leave it as is this time?

Comment: Copy paste please. (For future viewers). And it depends what your class looks like. Is the `String` property `private`?

Comment: searchString isn't, but in Movie.java yes.

Comment: How would I do this exactly? I can't seem to think of a way. My brain is just fried at this point I've been working on this class since I woke up. Would I have to do something similar to loadDatabse method?

Comment: Yeah sorry I hadn't seen the notification yet. So this definitely fixed it but my output came out weird all of them are "Movie@" plus random numbers and letters.

Comment: Yep. Updated. I added what you put in your post at the bottom of the first java class.

Comment: What is in the txt file?

Comment: Lots and lots of movie names, with their year and genre. It goes like this name\n year\n genre\n

Comment: `System.out.println(temp);` ---> `System.out.println(temp.toString());`

Comment: Oh yes! Finally thank you so much it works perfectly. (:

Comment: I'll update the code as well because I added the toString method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching if an `ArrayList` of `Movie` objects are equal to a `String`. I believe what you wanted to do is search for the `title` property (Or some similar `String` property) of the `Movie` class. So something like:

```
for(Movie movie: database) {
   if(movie.getName().equals(searchString)) {
      System.out.println(temp,toString());  
      //Convert the object to it's appropriate String representation
   }
}
```

And in your Movie class (So you can access your `private` variables outside of your class):

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the code by `temp.getName().contains`, since you are looking for characters under Movie object code has to be updated.

```
public static void printMatchingMovies(ArrayList<Movie> database, String searchString) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int numMatches = 0;

    for (Movie temp : database)
    {
        if (temp.getName().contains(searchString))
        {
            System.out.println(temp);
            numMatches++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of matches: " + numMatches);
}
```